# Fill target array with dynamically shifted source array

Tags: arrays, r

What is a good way to shift an array by a number given per column?

I have the following method to filling up a full size array ("o") with values of a different array ("p", all dimnames(p) exist in "o").

```
# empty target array 
o <- array(dim=c(6,3),dimnames=list(c(1:6),c(1:3))) 

# partially filled source array
p <- array(c(10:16),dim=c(2,3),dimnames=list(c(2:3),c(1:3)))  
> p
   1  2  3
2 10 12 14
3 11 13 15

# fill target array with p 
o[(match(names(p[,1]),names(o[,1]))),(match(names(p[1,]),names(o[1,])))] <- p 
> o 
   1  2  3 
1 NA NA NA 
2 10 12 14 
3 11 13 15 
4 NA NA NA 
5 NA NA NA 
6 NA NA NA
```

Now I would like to rewrite the matching array call to shift each column by the value in the column header (only for simplification I picked 1:3).

In this example, shift the first column by 1, the 2nd column by 2 and so on).

The result would look like this:

```
   1  2  3 
1 NA NA NA 
2 NA NA NA 
3 10 NA NA 
4 11 12 NA 
5 NA 13 14 
6 NA NA 15
```

Is there a good way to solve this without going into manual looping?

I have tried something in direction

```
o[(match(names(p[,1]),as.integer(names(o[,1]))-as.integer(names(o[1,])))),(match(names(p[1,]),names(o[1,])))] <- p
```

and to extract the colnames, but then had to go into looping.

Thanks

Comment: If you have only 2D arrays those are called matrices and `matrix` is a slightly more convenient constructor.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks - it's a multi dimensional array. I just showed 2d for illustration purpose. I can live with 0 instead of NA. Just checking your answer below.

Comment: Sparse matrices are 2D by definition. The function in my answer should be easy to extend to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shift <- function(M) {
  #find indices of non-NAs
  ind <- which(!is.na(M), arr.ind = TRUE)
  #create shifted indices
  ind_shifted <- ind
  ind_shifted[, "row"] <- ind_shifted[, "row"] + 
                             as.integer(colnames(M))[ind_shifted[, "col"]]
  #fill matrix with shifted values
  M_shifted <- M + NA
  M_shifted[ind_shifted] <- M[ind]
  M_shifted
}

shift(o)
#   1  2  3
#1 NA NA NA
#2 NA NA NA
#3 10 NA NA
#4 11 12 NA
#5 NA 13 14
#6 NA NA 15
```

If you could use zeros instead of `NA`s (i.e., `0` is not a valid value), you could do this more efficiently with sparse matrices.